# Is language regular?

Tags: regular-languages

Suppose we have language $a^{\binom{n}{k}} n,k \in N$ is this language regular ? If it is not, I should use pummping-lemma? It it is regular, I will use proof by induction ?

Comment: What do you think? What have you tried?

Comment: 1. I'm not sure what your language is.  Can you proof-read it and use standard notation?  I suspect you are missing some symbols from the definition of the language.

Comment: 2. What have you tried?  Your question is a very basic one. Since you [did 
not include much of an attempt to solve it on your own](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594), we have little to
work with. Let me direct you towards our 
[reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599)
which cover your problem in detail.
Please work through the related questions listed there, try to solve your 
problem again and edit to include your attempts along with the specific 
problems you encountered.  Is there any reason this question should not be closed as a duplicate of one of those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. For any integer $n>0$, $\binom{n}{1}=n$, so can you specify what strings are in your language?

Comment: Okay, so, because of hint $a^{n}$ strings are like w4 = a.a.a.a (n-times concatenated language a)

Comment: Yup. So your language is at least $\{a^m\mid m>0\}$ and it might be larger than that if you adopt the convention that $\binom{n}{k}=0$, as many people do. Both of there are, of course, regular.